# does in_array() not allow duplicates?

Tags: php

Alright, so i've got this code here (it's from a class)

```
    function getResourceXML($id)
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('resources.xml');
        $array = array();
        foreach($xml->catagory->resource as $children)
        {
            if(in_array($children['id'], $id))
            {
                array_push( $array, (string)$children['income'] );
            }
            print_r($array);
            echo '<br />';

        }
        return $array;  

    }
    function getResourceMultiplier()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT resourceArray FROM starinformation WHERE starOwner = :uid";
        $que = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $que->bindParam('uid', $this->uid);
        $resource = array();
        try 
        {
            $que->execute();
            while($row = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))
            {
                array_push($resource, $row[0]);
            }
            $resource = $this->getResourceXML($resource);
            return $resource;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {}
    }
```

I had to alter it after I realized my live server is php 4 instead of 5. It was working until i got ride of all the $array[] elements. now the array_push isn't inserting duplicate entries (at least I think that's what is going on)

Comment: `array_push` pushes into an array whatever you want. Your problem must be something else. Some debug output should show you when your code starts to do something which is not intended.

Comment: `array_push()` is another way to say `$array[]`, does not check for duplicates.

Comment: The array key must be unique otherwise the latter key defined will overwrite the previous. i.e $resource needs to be unique each pass.

Comment: A question like this is often answered (ie explained in detail) in the main docs: http://uk1.php.net/in_array. Also, you should consider upgrading from PHP 4 (if you cannot then fine, but at least consider it)

Comment: Are you sure you're on PHP 4? It's been obsolete for almost a decade. And it did not, to the best of my knowledge, include PDO or simplexml. You should also mention what it's doing wrong, versus what you expect it to be doing. Is this the original code or your changed code?